# How to pass a string in NodeJS Sequelize to SQL query without quotes?

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

Im passing a variables to a sql query from the nodejs sequelize.

The code something like this:

```
const query= 'select * from data order by orderid :order'
```

Im passing the order as either ASC or DESC from the nodejs part

```
const result = await sequelize.query(query, {
      replacements:{order},
      type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT,
    },);
```

But, the order is being passed with quotes like 'ASC' or 'DESC'.
How can I pass it without quotes like ASC or DESC?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Im passing many more parameters so this is best approach I have.

Comment: ASC/DESC can't be passed as parameters. If orderid is an integer, you can multiply by 1 or -1, depending on ASC or DESC.

Comment: You cannot replace keywords with placeholder, since placeholder substitutes the data, not some text in SQL query. And of course it is also part of syntax and is processed at parsing stage (before anything was passed to the variable).